# Loading bootstrap modal from Ajax change button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I’m launching a bootstrap modal using a button and then changing the button class and text via jQuery. I want to launch another bootstrap modal once the button class is changed.

Here is my code

```
$('.btn myBtn1').click(function () {
   var id = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
$('#myModal1').data('id', id).modal('show');
 $('. btn').addClass(' myBtn2');
$('. btn').removeClass(' myBtn1');

});
//second modal code
$('.btn myBtn2').click(function () {
  var id = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
$('#myModal2').data('id', id).modal('show');
 $('. btn').addClass(' myBtn1');
$('. btn'). removeClass(' myBtn2');

});
```

My issue is its launching the same modal. Modal 1 and never loads the modal two. What should I do to fix this? Appreciate your time.

Comment: This `$('.btn myBtn2').click(...)` is called *before* the button has that class, at a time at which the selector doesn't match anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following line of code:

```
//second modal code
$('.btn myBtn2').click(function () {
```

to

```
//second modal code
$(document).on('click', '.btn myBtn2', function(){
```

**Reason:** When you are changing the selectors dynamically than you have to make your event listeners also capable of handling that. 
`$('selector').click();` works for static selectors only.

Answer (score 1):

You have changed button class dynamically so client event is not attached. In this case you have click event attached with parent instead of child. More info [In jQuery, how to attach events to dynamic html elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements)

Use this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn myBtn2', function () {
```